# Erro ao importar banco Banco de dados do Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Estou com problemas ao importar o Banco de dados do Wordpress.

Em meu servidor físico local, com Ubuntu server 16.04 está rodando, mas quando joguei no meu Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, não funciona.

Os procedimentos realizados foram:

1. Exportar _SQL pelo phpmyadmin do servidor.
2. Importar banco de dados pelo mysql Workbench
3. Mudei o endereço em WP-Option para o meu localhost/projeto

Quando acesso a página, localhost/projeto, a tela fica em branco. O que eu posso fazer para resolver este problema?

Comment: O que tem no log de erros do PHP? Va em wp-config.php e coloque `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` e tente de novo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Ricardo...mas ainda a tela esta em branco! Quando pressiono f12 no firefox para colher alguma informação, surge essa informação:

Comment: `?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
`